# How to add functions like generating random UUID in velocity template for request/response mapping in API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, vtl

I am creating a request mapping template for AWS API gateway. In that template I want to customize the request params based on certain conditions and apply operators.

```
 #foreach($header in $input.params().header.keySet())
     #if($header=="id")#set($idVal = 
     $util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($header)))
         #if($idVal.matches("^[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9A-Z]{3}$"))
             "$header":"$idVal"
         #else
           #set($random = UUID.randomUUID())
          "$header":"$random"
         #end
     #else
```

For example, in the above template based on if condition I want to generate randomUUID and add to the header. But when I test, the id value is set to empty string.

How can I use packages and java functions support in velocity template mapping api gateway? Also, please share any reference to wellformed template, it would be really useful to learn more.

Answer (score 10):

VTL as used in API Gateway is not extensible with your own packages.  Only the [built-in variables and `$util` functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html) can be used.

You may find that `$context.requestId` contains a suitable UUID for your purpose, unique to each request.  Note that if you are using a Lambda integration, this value differs from Lambda's `context.requestId` which only coincidentally has the same name.

Or, the rightmost 33 characters of `$context.xrayTraceId` should contain a 4 byte timestamp (8 hex digits) + '-' + a 96-bit unique value (24 hex digits) from which you could construct a serviceable UUID with some light string manipulation.

Comment: `$context.requestId` is what is mentioned in the AWS blog for the hash key: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/

Answer (score 2):

For AppSync users:

You can't use packages but you can use the [$util helpers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-util-reference.html)

For example you can use `$util.autoId()` to generate your UUID.

Comment: Note: This is applicable to App Sync only